# Security of registering on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, registration, identity

There's something on my mind so I decided to ask. Is the default registration (for example in default ASP.NET MVC project) through ASP.NET Identity safe? I mean, by default we send to server pure password, that is possible to be catched by someone isn't it? What could I do to improve it? I read few articles and the only thing I noticed is that hashing on client's side is as good as on server's and there's no point in.

Comment: It's not about server implementation but connection you're using. With HTTPS login page (not just AFTER login) then you're _safe_ (ironic emphasis intended). With HTTP then a _man-in-the-middle_ may stole your credentials. BTW hashing client side does not improve security (in this case). Anyway topic is pretty vast...

Comment: HTTPS will make it safe? Isn't there still a possibility to catch the password?

Comment: Yes and no. It's _safe_ but someone in the middle that pretends to be the server may still get all client requests and then route them to server pretending to be the client. Of course client can detect this because its certificate is (should be) broken (but it's client user responsibility to verify this). If you want to enforce this you may need to also give a certificate to each client (and server will then also validate clients). You may take a look to security.stackexchange for this topic

Comment: Huge topic with an entire industry devoted to it.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Nathan I expected something like Adriano's answer, not really specific but general

Answer (score 1):

An SSL certificate could be used to encrypt the traffic sent to the login endpoint to prevent sending the credentials cleartext. This mitigates the risk of man-in-the-middle attacks where the traffic can be intercepted. As long as you have a valid domain and a valid SSL certificate for this domain, using it to encrypt the traffic will mitigate the risk of decrypting any intercepted traffic and thus exposing the credentials.

This being said you should not only protect the login endpoint with SSL. Many people believe that this is sufficient. Once a session is established, all traffic should be encrypted because another possible attack vector is the authentication cookie. This cookie can also be intercepted by man-in-the-middle, so you should ensure that it is marked with the `secure` flag so that it only transits over a secure and encrypted channel.

With the upcoming HTTP 2/SPDY protocol those security issues will be decreased because everything is encrypted over HTTPS.